# "Equals" boolean with logic gates?

Tags: logic

How would you represent the boolean $A=B$ visually in terms of logic gates? Assuming a 4-bit system (i.e. the two inputs $A$ and $B$ would never exceed 4 bits).

## Example

If $A=3$, then the system returns $0$ for all inputs $B$ other than $B=3$ (where it returns $1$).

Comment: Hint: if $a,b$ are 1-bit, then $a=b$ can be expressed by `not(xor(a,b))` ... happy combining.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a possible answer is simply a series of XOR gates with each input the same place on both bits, then the output of each of these is fed into a tree of OR gates terminating in a single output.

Comment: That makes sense. All though after the tree of OR gates, you'd need to negate the final output.

Comment: @Graviton ahh yes. Simple fix